# a function runs multiple times when showing a bootstrap modal. vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I have a `button` that shows a `bootstrap` modal, it has an `onclick` attribute set to a function,

The button:

```html
<span style="color:blue;margin-left: 2rem;" data-id="{{student.id}}" id="{{student.id}}"
   type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#grade-modal" 
   onClick="getEnrolledSubjects(this.getAttribute('data-id'))">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</span>
```

My javascript function:

```js
function getEnrolledSubjects(id){
    var modal = document.getElementById('grade-modal')
    modal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        console.log(id)
    }
}
```

at first, it looks fine because it will only log the `id` once, but when I close the modal and open it again, it will log 2 times, then 3 times, and so on... it goes incrementally. how can i fix this?

Comment: The issue is that you are adding _another_ listener to the same modal's shown event every time... Without ever removing one. Maybe the listener shouldn't even be assigned in the button click handler in the first place, but once outside.

Comment: It's probaly because you add a new `addEventListener` every time you call the function!

Comment: ohhh so should i just call modal.show()?

Comment: An event listener is just to be set once, and then it just sits here and listend all the time. Every time it "hears" the event it's listening for, it triggers the corresponding action.

Comment: Can you create create stackblitz sample?

Comment: You have to choose: Bootstrap or VanillaJS. You can't use both. They're not compatible.

Comment: I think you can use `relatedTarget` and get `id` of `relatedTarget`

Comment: I think you can use `relatedTarget` and get `id` of `relatedTarget`

Answer (score 0):

as [Bootstrap Modal documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

You can Use `event.relatedTarget`:

```
<span style="color:blue;margin-left: 2rem;" data-id="{{student.id}}" id="{{student.id}}" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#grade-modal">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
</span>
```

without `onClick` event

```
const modal = document.getElementById('grade-modal')
modal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function(event){
    const button = event.relatedTarget
    const id = button.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log(id)
})
```